# Rails change routing of submit in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-submit

I have a model 'Article' and a model 'Ratings' nested within articles.

/articles/123/ratings

I want to change the routing of the f.submit in ratings/_form.html.erb
now it is so, that after pressing submit, my application routs to

/ratings/111

but I want to route it to

/article/123

How can I change the routing in a form_for f.submit button.
I have found here something like this:

```
<% form_for :thing, :url => 
 url_for(:action => "update", :id => @thing) do |f| %>
```

But this do not work for my rails 3.2. Thanks for your help,

Comment: You forgot to add `=` after `<%`.
Unfortunately I did not understand at what controller and action you want to send the form.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

:url - The URL the form is submitted to. It takes the same fields you pass to url_for or link_to. In particular you may pass here a named route directly as well. Defaults to the current action.

```
<% form_for :thing, :url => {:action => "update", :id => @thing} do |f| %>
```

you can also pass it the path_name by using the helper. so you can also do something like

```
:url => update_article_path(@article)
```

Comment: no this do not work for me >> form_for(@rating), :url => (:action => "show", :id => @article) do |f| >> the error that I get are this >> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end...nd=

Answer (score 5):

Try `form_for (:thing, url:{:controller=>'thing', :action=>'update'}, html:{method:'put'})`.