# Rails <%= form_for(:user, url: users_path) do |f| %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What is the difference between this

```
<%= form_for(:user, url: users_path) do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

Why is the `users_path` necessary and what is it doing?

Why in the first form is the `:user` symbol used and not `@user`?

Comment: Good example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414514/rails-change-routing-of-submit-in-form-for and also docs here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 1):

In the first way --

```
<%= form_for(:user, url: users_path) do |f| %>
```

you will get the exact same form html wise (for example `<input name="user[age]" />`)

BUT

When you provide a specific @user object (that you define in the controller) the fields will be filed with the information saved in the @user var.

for example, if I define a @user in the controller and say

```
@user.age = 5
```

and than I do a form_for and load put an input for a name it will already fill it with "gilad":

```
<input name="user[age]" value=5 />
```

Also, in the first type of form the :url is the url the form will be submitted to.

Hope this helped